# numba: vectorizing a function with string input/return

Tags: python, pandas, string, vectorization, numba

I have a sample function which I want to vectorize with numba:

```
import numba

@numba.vectorize
def test(x: str):
    return x.strip()
```

and a pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["test ", "   test", "  test   ", "test"]})
```

now if I want to call the function

```
test(df.A.to_numpy())
```

I get an `{TypeError}return type must be specified for object mode` Error.
`@numba.vectorize("unicode_type(unicode_type)")` also doesn't work.

Is it possible to vectorize functions with string input?

Comment: did you find any way around it, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I used the workaround with `@numba.jit` posted below

Answer (score 0):

If I use `numba.jit` its working:

```
@numba.jit
def test(string_array: np.ndarray):
    n=string_array.size
    result=np.empty(n,dtype="U10")
    for i in range(n):
        result[i]=string_array[i].strip()
    return result
```